# Complex analysis: $\log(z^{m})=m\log(z)$, $\forall m\in\mathbb{Z}\setminus${$0$}

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms

I'm reviewing some elementary properties in complex analysis, and I came across with the following statement: $\log(z^m)=m\log(z)$, $\forall m\in\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}$.

First, let's recall that by definition, we have $\log(z) = \left\{\ln|z| + i\theta \mid \theta\in \arg(z)\right\}$.

This is my attempt to prove one inclusion of this steatment:

Let $w \in\log(z)$. So we have $w = \ln|z^m|+i\theta$, for some $\theta\in\arg(z^m)$.
Now we can use the argument property: $\arg(z^m)=\underbrace{\arg(z)+\dots+\arg(z)}_{m\ \text{times}}$.

So that implies the existence of $\theta_j\in\arg(z)$, $1\leq j \leq m$ such that $\theta = \displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^{m}\theta_j$

Therefore, using the property of real logarithm we obtain: \begin{equation*}w =\underbrace{\ln|z| + \cdots + \ln|z|}_{m\ \text{times}} + i(\theta_1+\cdots+\theta_m) = (\ln|z| + i\theta_1) + \cdots +(\ln|z| + i\theta_m)\end{equation*}
Then, we have $w_k = \ln|z| + i\theta_k\in\log(z)$, $1\leq k\leq m$.

Hence, it was proved that $w=w_1 + \cdots + w_m \in m\log(z)$.

Is this correct? If so, my intuition tells me that the a similar argument proves the other inclusion.
I don't know, maybe I miss something.

Comment: I think you are misusing the symbol $\in$ - do you just mean $=$?

Comment: When you wrote $\theta\in\arg(\theta)$, did you mean $\theta\in\arg(z)$?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math SE. Bear in mind the equality can only be to within a term $\in2\pi i\Bbb Z$. Consider e.g. $z=-1,\,m=2$.

Comment: I think either you are getting the definition wrong, or you are using a non-standard definition. $\log(z)$ and $\arg(z)$ are usually numbers, not sets. You might be using $\arg(z)$ to mean "all possible arguments of $z$", but if so I think there are still mistakes. Could you clarify, please?

Comment: Yes, I mean $\theta\in\arg(z)$. Sorry, it was a typo. Now it is correct.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean @preferred_anon. In the complex case, there is an infinity of logarithms of a non-zero complex number.

Comment: @JoelMarques Nevertheless, $\log(z)$ is not usually defined as the set of all possible logarithms. It looks like you are defining it as a multifunction, which is fine - I just wanted to clarify, because it is unusual.